# Deploying Java application into WebLogic 10.3.6

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic-10.x

I've developed a Java application and generated a WAR and tried to deploy it into our weblogic server 10.3.6, while doing that i'm getting this error on weblogic console: working fine in local. 
1. Unable to access the selected appliation 
2. Exception in Appmerge flows' progression 
3. Exception in Appmerge flows' progression 
4. Unmarshaller failed

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
TransferReceive

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.pos.extra</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Can some one help me why i'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message including the stack trace from the weblogic server's log file plz.